# can't use bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm experiencing some difficulties when using the command: "bundle install". It's probably some kind of a trivial issue, but I would appreciate any help you can give. I am using linux ubuntu 11.04, ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [i686-linux]

The error message I get is this :

```
/var/www/hw2_rottenpotatoes$ bundle install
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using multi_json (1.0.4) 
Using activesupport (3.1.0) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using activemodel (3.1.0) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.3.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.0.3) 
Using rack-mount (0.8.3) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.0.3) 
Using actionpack (3.1.0) 
Using mime-types (1.17.2) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.3.0) 
Using actionmailer (3.1.0) 
Using arel (2.2.1) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.31) 
Using activerecord (3.1.0) 
Using activeresource (3.1.0) 
Using bundler (1.1.3) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.2.0) 
Using execjs (1.2.13) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.6.3) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.1.0) 
Using coffee-rails (3.1.1) 
Using haml (3.1.4) 
Using jquery-rails (1.0.19) 
Using libv8 (3.3.10.4) 
Using pg (0.13.1) 
Using rails (3.1.0) 
Using sass (3.1.12) 
Using sass-rails (3.1.5) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.5) 
Using therubyracer (0.9.9) 
Using uglifier (1.2.2) 
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Please include the full output of the command, your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. Thanks!
/home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:246:in `initialize': Permission denied - /var/www/hw2_rottenpotatoes/Gemfile.lock (Errno::EACCES)
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:246:in `open'
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:246:in `lock'
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:39:in `lock'
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:59:in `run'
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12:in `install'
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /home/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>
```

my Gemfile is :

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# for Heroku deployment - as described in Ap. A of ELLS book
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'therubyracer'              
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
gem 'haml'
```

and my Gemfile.lock is :

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.0)
      actionpack (= 3.1.0)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.0)
      activemodel (= 3.1.0)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.2)
      rack-cache (~> 1.0.3)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.0)
    activemodel (3.1.0)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.0)
      activemodel (= 3.1.0)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.0)
      activemodel (= 3.1.0)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)
    activesupport (3.1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
    arel (2.2.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    columnize (0.3.5)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.2.13)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    haml (3.1.4)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.19)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.3)
    libv8 (3.3.10.4)
    linecache19 (0.5.12)
      ruby_core_source (>= 0.1.4)
    mail (2.3.0)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    multi_json (1.0.4)
    pg (0.13.1)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.3.5)
    rack-cache (1.0.3)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.0)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.0)
      actionpack (= 3.1.0)
      activerecord (= 3.1.0)
      activeresource (= 3.1.0)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.0)
    railties (3.1.0)
      actionpack (= 3.1.0)
      activesupport (= 3.1.0)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      linecache19 (>= 0.5.11)
      ruby_core_source (>= 0.1.4)
    ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      linecache19 (>= 0.5.11)
      ruby-debug-base19 (>= 0.11.19)
    ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
      archive-tar-minitar (>= 0.5.2)
    sass (3.1.12)
    sass-rails (3.1.5)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    sprockets (2.0.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5)
    therubyracer (0.9.9)
      libv8 (~> 3.3.10)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.31)
    uglifier (1.2.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.1.0)
  haml
  jquery-rails
  pg
  rails (= 3.1.0)
  ruby-debug19
  sass-rails (~> 3.1.0)
  sqlite3
  therubyracer
  uglifier
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like bundler doesn't have rights to access Gemfile and/or Gemfile.lock make sure the permissions are right on those files.

Comment: Also check permissions on the directory (`/var/www/`) as well as the individual files.

Answer (score 0):

Being on Ubuntu, you might want to work on your app in `/home/<username>/` where you should have more permissions.
If you are working in the `/var/` directory, you might need to use sudo everywhere.